# Get User Id by JWT Token in ASP.NET Boilerplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I added JWT Auth to my asp.net boilerplate project.

I try to get user identity (ideally will be Id) by Token

Here is how I try to do this.

```
[Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ShowJobDto), (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetJobs(DateTime? from, DateTime? to)
    {
        var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
        List<ShowJobDto> jobs;
        var query = _jobRepository.GetAllIncluding(x => x.WorkOrder.Quote,
            x => x.WorkOrder.Quote.Property.Addresses,
            x => x.Engineer).Where(x => x.JobStatus != JobStatus.Pending);
        if (from != null && to != null)
        {
            jobs = await query.Where(x => x.JobDate >= from).Where(x => x.JobDate <= to)
                .ProjectTo<ShowJobDto>(ObjectMapper).OrderBy(x => x.TimeFrom).ToListAsync();
            return Ok(jobs);
        }

        jobs = await query.ProjectTo<ShowJobDto>(ObjectMapper).OrderBy(x => x.TimeFrom).ToListAsync();
        return Ok(jobs);
    }
```

I postman I pass beare token like this

[image]

But when I set breakpoint here `var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;`

I got nothing. Where is my problem?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the following approach in order to Authorize users in one of my app.
So I'm sure you can make some changes to this code and get what you need:

First you need to get the header and strip down the Bearer from it.

```
string authHeaderValue = Request.Headers["Authorization"];
```

Then you need to use ClaimsPrincipal to validate your Token which is part of System.Security.Claims

This is a simple presentation of it in a class:

```
public ClaimsPrincipal GetClaims(string token)
{
    var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var validations = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
         ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
         IssuerSigningKey = SIGNING_KEY,
         ValidateIssuer = false,
         ValidateAudience = false
    };

    return handler.ValidateToken(token, validations, out var tokenSecure);
}
```

Note that ValidateToken is part of System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;

Here is how to strip down the Bearer from the token

```
var tokenClaims = GetClaims(authHeaderValue.Substring("Bearer ".Length).Trim());
```

Then you can look for user Identity or whatever you need in your Token:

```
var userId = tokenClaims.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

In my case I stored userId in NameIdentifier. So change it according to your settings.

One more thing. Make sure that your Token isn't expired while you are testing your application.

Hope it helps.